# custom JCR module not used by wildfly

Tags: module, wildfly

I am trying to run jackrabbit 2.6.4 as JCA on a wildfly 8.0 server. It was already running on Jboss 7.1. One important requirement of jackrabbit is JCR 2.0 api (jcr-2.0.jar).
I configuered this as a custom module with taking care the structure "modules\javax\jcr\main" including the "module.xml" file

inside my wildfly configuration i configured JCR in this this way:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:1.0">
        <resource-adapters>
            <resource-adapter id="jackrabbit-jca-2.6.4.rar">
                <archive>
                    jackrabbit-jca-2.6.4.rar
                </archive>
                <transaction-support>XATransaction</transaction-support>
                <connection-definitions>
                    <connection-definition class-name="org.apache.jackrabbit.jca.JCAManagedConnectionFactory" jndi-name="jcrJCA" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="jackrabbit-jca-x.x.x_rar-Pool" use-ccm="true">
                        <config-property name="configFile">
                            E:\jackrabbit\repository.xml
                        </config-property>
                        <config-property name="bindSessionToTransaction">
                            true
                        </config-property>
                        <config-property name="homeDir">
                            E:\jackrabbit\repository
                        </config-property>
                    </connection-definition>
                </connection-definitions>
            </resource-adapter>
        </resource-adapters>
    </subsystem>
```

The Error that appears during startup is:

```
    15:17:22,880 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.ra.deployer."jackrabbit-jca
-2.6.4.rar": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.ra.deployer."jackrabbit-jca-2.6.4.rar": JBAS010446: Failed to start RA deployment [
jackrabbit-jca-2.6.4.rar]
        at org.jboss.as.connector.services.resourceadapters.deployment.ResourceAdapterDeploymentService$1.run(ResourceAdapterDeploymentService.java:15
7)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.DeployException: IJ020056: Deployment failed: file:/E:/wildfly-8.0.0.Final/standalone/tmp/vfs/temp/t
emp3f670452d6c2c4d4/jackrabbit-jca-2.6.4.rar-420b5a12409fe1b4/contents/
        at org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.AbstractResourceAdapterDeployer.createObjectsAndInjectValue(AbstractResourceAdapterDeployer.java:2611) [iron
jacamar-deployers-common-1.1.3.Final.jar:1.1.3.Final]
        at org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.AbstractResourceAdapterDeployer.createObjectsAndInjectValue(AbstractResourceAdapterDeployer.java:1171) [iron
jacamar-deployers-common-1.1.3.Final.jar:1.1.3.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.connector.services.resourceadapters.deployment.ResourceAdapterDeploymentService$AS7RaDeployer.doDeploy(ResourceAdapterDeployme
ntService.java:209)
        at org.jboss.as.connector.services.resourceadapters.deployment.ResourceAdapterDeploymentService.start(ResourceAdapterDeploymentService.java:11
8)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jcr/RepositoryException
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at org.jboss.jca.validator.ValidateClass.<init>(ValidateClass.java:88) [ironjacamar-validator-1.1.3.Final.jar:1.1.3.Final]
        at org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.AbstractResourceAdapterDeployer.createObjectsAndInjectValue(AbstractResourceAdapterDeployer.java:1938) [iron
jacamar-deployers-common-1.1.3.Final.jar:1.1.3.Final]
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jcr.RepositoryException from [Module "deployment.jackrabbit-jca-2.6.4.rar:main" from Service Module
 Loader]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:197) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
        ... 12 more
```

Therefore i suppose that the JCR module ist not found/used correctly because the class "javax.jcr.RepositoryException" is inside the module jar.
How could i tell wildfly that this module has to be used?
Is there any workaround?
Thanking you very much in advance for any help

kind regards,

shane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the guide under the link
[Jackrabbit on JBoss 7](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JackrabbitDeploymentInAS6AndAS7)

in my case, the problem was, thath i did not modiefied the manifest inside the rar
I had to add the line

```
Dependencies: javax.jcr export,org.slf4j
```

Best regards
shane